# How to get ListView cells value

Tags: wpf, listview

I have `ListView` with 2 columns and simple `ContextMenu`:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem
            Name="menuItemCopy"
            Header="Copy"
            Click="menuItemCopy_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

And my Copy `ClickEvent`:

```
private void menuItemCopy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;
    var item = listView.SelectedItems[0];
    MyItem myItem = item as MyItem;
    string val = myItem.Value;
    Clipboard.SetText(val);
}
```

Ok so this works fine and i can get my first column value, but if i want to get the second column ?

Comment: why not simply `myItem.SecondColumnProperty`?

Comment: I don't see any mention of columns in your source code. Also, are you using `ListView` or `ListBox`?

Comment: string valcol2 = myItem.ColProperty2 will do. How your datasource looks like and your ListView looks like ?

Comment: I meas how to distingushed between column1 right click or column2 right click ?